# Why i cant deserialize Json array C#?

Tags: c#, json

I try to deserialize this Json: [image: JsonStruct]

I have array pictures: [image: JsonStruct]

And I have this C# code:

```
 class KickStarterJson
{
   public List<ProjectInfo> projects { get; set; }
    public  int total_hits { get; set; }
    public  int live_projects_count { get; set; }
}
class ProjectInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int pledged { get; set; } 
    public string currency { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try to deserialize this Json I catch this error:
[image: Error]

Json: `"name":"Help Us Grow our Fleet with a Go Bananas Food Trailer","blurb":"We are ready to take our business to the next level by adding a Go Bananas Food Trailer to our fleet to operate in MN and AZ.","goal":12000.0,"pledged":0.0,"state":"live","slug":"help-us-grow-our-fleet-with-a-go-bananas-food-trai","disable_communication":false,"country":"US","currency":"USD","currency_symbol":"$","currency_trailing_code":true,"deadline":1549975076,"state_changed_at":1544791076,"created_at":1544049789,"launched_at":1544791076,"staff_pick":false,"is_starrable":true,"backers_count":0,"static_usd_rate":1.0,"usd_pledged":"0.0","converted_pledged_amount":0,"fx_rate":1.0,"current_currency":"USD","usd_type":"international","creator":{"id":469256311,"name":"Lisa Bastien","slug":"gobananas","is_registered":null,"chosen_currency":null,"avatar":{"thumb":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/023/484/870/b425950910db87fbf3db68cf6af0ba32_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&w=40&h=40&fit=crop&v=1544055848&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=f6df473d01d0ae8e957ef915fc57d089","small":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/023/484/870/b425950910db87fbf3db68cf6af0ba32_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&w=160&h=160&fit=crop&v=1544055848&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=4c560ceb28103abb9aa977df12c0e43d","medium":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/023/484/870/b425950910db87fbf3db68cf6af0ba32_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&w=160&h=160&fit=crop&v=1544055848&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=4c560ceb28103abb9aa977df12c0e43d"},"urls":{"web":{"user":"https://www.kickstarter.com/profile/gobananas"},"api":{"user":"https://api.kickstarter.com/v1/users/469256311?signature=1544879587.06bd700b38861ad1b10b98000d2029cdb52fd839"}}},"location":{"id":2487129,"name":"St. Paul","slug":"st-paul-mn","short_name":"St. Paul, MN","displayable_name":"St. Paul, MN","localized_name":"St. Paul","country":"US","state":"MN","type":"Town","is_root":false,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/places/st-paul-mn","location":"https://www.kickstarter.com/locations/st-paul-mn"},"api":{"nearby_projects":"https://api.kickstarter.com/v1/discover?signature=1544866329.8e94c3149b792ab1670a78bcc28d58b8acb9e302&woe_id=2487129"}}},"category":{"id":311,"name":"Food Trucks","slug":"food/food trucks","position":8,"parent_id":10,"color":16725570,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/food/food%20trucks"}}},"profile":{"id":3529735,"project_id":3529735,"state":"inactive","state_changed_at":1544049789,"name":null,"blurb":null,"background_color":null,"text_color":null,"link_background_color":null,"link_text_color":null,"link_text":null,"link_url":null,"show_feature_image":false,"background_image_opacity":0.8,"should_show_feature_image_section":true,"feature_image_attributes":{"image_urls":{"default":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/023/483/978/b425950910db87fbf3db68cf6af0ba32_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&crop=faces&w=1552&h=873&fit=crop&v=1544050003&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=5593a7650dbff908681a5d42abcaee51","baseball_card":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/023/483/978/b425950910db87fbf3db68cf6af0ba32_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&crop=faces&w=560&h=315&fit=crop&v=1544050003&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=1460cab50f8a4968d759ec34d1cf91d5"}}},"spotlight":false,"urls":{"web":{"project":"https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/gobananas/help-us-grow-our-fleet-with-a-go-bananas-food-trai?ref=newest","rewards":"https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/gobananas/help-us-grow-our-fleet-with-a-go-bananas-food-trai/rewards"}}}`

Text error: System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and include your error as text

Comment: You haven't shown the actual JSON string that you are trying to deserialize. (what is `response`?)

Comment: And also the json.

Comment: response it is json (string )

Comment: But please provide us *with* that JSON, as a string representation. The debugger screenshots don't help nearly as much as the plain text.

Comment: That exception is telling you that the string in `response` is not valid JSON. So if you show us the value of the string, we can help show you why.

Comment: How I show you Json code . it is huge .

Comment: I was add json file

Comment: Please, let us ask it once more: post your JSON and error messages as text. NOT IMAGES, NO LINKS!

Comment: Your problem is the `pledged` property. You declared it as `int`, but in the JSON it is `0.0`. Declare it as `decimal` instead: `public decimal pledged { get; set; }`.

Comment: No problem with array of projects

Comment: Your array is fine. Just your `pledged` property is wrong.

Comment: Really you right , thank you ). And sorry for my bad "question"

Comment: @DmytroKrypto Why did you accept an answer that was just plain wrong?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Dude updated his answer with my answer. I was about to post an answer when the question got closed, which is why I posted it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
};

var kickStarterJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KickStarterJson>(jsonResponse, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

EDIT: The actual error is that *pledged* must be a decimal, and not an integer.

Use this class instead:

```
class ProjectInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal pledged { get; set; } 
    public string currency { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What problem does that fix?

Comment: Just need to change type on decimal

Comment: My first thought was that the mapping was failing since his model does not correspond to the source.